# Mock de usuário para testes no Laravel/PHPUnit

Tags: laravel, phpunit

Estou com uma aplicação legada em Laravel onde os usuários podem ver ou não determinado módulo do sistema de acordo com suas permissões. Essas permissões são gravadas no banco de dados de forma N:N e gerenciadas no UserPolicy.

Segue um exemplo:

```
public function viewReports(User $user)
{
    foreach($user->module as $m){
        if($m->id === 3)
            return true;
    }
}
```

Para que eu possa refatorar o código, preciso escrever testes afim de garantir que as mudanças não quebrem o código. Porém não sei como proceder. Momentaneamente escrevi o seguinte teste apenas para me certificar do funcionamento, mas sei que não é uma boa prática (já que estou usando dados registrados no banco de dados):

```
    public function testCanViewReports()
    {
        $user = User::findOrFail(1);

        $this->assertTrue($user->can('viewReports', User::class));
    }
```

> Qual a melhor forma de criar um dublê para esse teste sem depender do
>   banco de dados?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A melhor forma é utilizando Factories e Faker.

Você pode usar o comando 
`php artisan make:factory UserFactory`.

a factory será criada na pasta "/app/database/factories/"
neste arquivo você pode definir dados fake para a model desejada.
basta retornar um array com os dados default da factory
Aqui você pode utilizar o faker para gerar dados fictícios para a sua factory

```
$factory->define(App\User::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name'           => $faker->name,
        'email'          => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
        'password'       => bcrypt('123456')
    ];
});
```

Documentação da Factory
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/database-testing#factory-states

Documentação do Faker:
https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker#basic-usage

No método do seu teste você pode utilizar a factory da seguinte forma.

`$user = factory(App\User::class)->make();`

apenas para ter uma instancia do Model User com dados fictícios, ou.

`$user = factory(App\User::class)->create();`

neste caso ele cria uma instancia da model e também insere os dados no banco.

para sobrescrever algum dado que você deseja, basta informar dentro do método create ou make da seguinte forma.

```
$user = factory(App\User::class)->create([
    'name' => 'João'
]);
```

O certo é nunca fazer testes utilizando a base de produção.
Uma outra coisa que você pode adicionar no seu teste é a trait "DatabaseTransactions", que faz rollback de todas as alterações feitas no banco durante o seu teste, não deixando assim esses dados que você gerou.